# I do not get show data in the datatable angular 2.x

Tags: django, angular, typescript

well, I make a web app with django and angular, the API is good but I'm newbie with angular and I don't understand that I'm wrong.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListarPersonasService {
  public personas:any = null;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public obtenerPersonas() {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/abogado/personas';
    return this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.personas = res;
        console.log(res);           
      }
    ); 
  }
}
```

this is my service, on the component the service to make the request is called and store the result in the variable datasource

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListarPersonasService } from "../servicios/listar-personas.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-listar-personas',
  templateUrl: './listar-personas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listar-personas.component.css']
})
export class ListarPersonasComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['documento','nombre', 'apellido'];
  dataSource : any;
  constructor(private listar:ListarPersonasService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = this.listar.obtenerPersonas()
  }
}
```

and here this html.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="persona" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="documento">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>documento</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.documento}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nombre}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="apellido">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Apellido</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.apellido}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

here is the result in console

```
{count: 2, next: null, previous: null, results: Array(2)}
 count: 2
 next: null
 previous: null
 results: Array(2)
  0: {id: 2, documento: 200, nombre: "martin", apellido: "De Francisco", nacimiento:"2020-02-05", …}
  1: {id: 1, documento: 205, nombre: "rafael", apellido: "escalona",nacimiento:"2020-02-05", …}
 length: 2
 __proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
 client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
```

I appreciate any suggestion that can guide me.

Comment: can you return the  ' this.personas = res; ' and add ' res:any ' at  subscribe .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code. There are few mistake inside your code.

1. Use this

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

instead of

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="persona" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

2. `this.personas` declare in your service but you are using this variable inside your html part. So you need to subscribe your api inside you component as following...

```
  //In service
  public obtenerPersonas() {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/abogado/personas';
    return this.http.get(url);
  }

  //in your-component.ts file
  this.listar.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(res => {
        this.dataSource = res;
        console.log(res);           
  });
```

and in the last, if you have not install all material which you are using right now  then must be install it first. you can see following Angular material official example.
[Click here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vnylqebvnog?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts)

I hope it is helpful for you. :)

Comment: sorry but don't work, please read the console result that I put.

Comment: sorry boy, you have razon my fault ready, every works. thank you

Answer (score 0):

service. Should be without subscribe. Otherwise it returns subscription instead of Observable.

```
public obtenerPersonas() {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/abogado/personas';
    return this.http.get(url); 
  }
```

Component. Do like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.listar.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(data => {
    // OR ADD HERE SOME NECESSARY DATA TRANSFROMATION AND DATA VALIDATION
    this.dataSource = data.personas;
  })
}
```

In template:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

So logic is:
- API service has a method that returns only Observable
- Component subscribes to this observable and angular does the HTTP request
- you get 'personas' from the response and set it as dataSource for your table

Comment: I understand what you want to say  but my function return a object with information for pagination and a array where is the information that is put into the table, when save the array information neither works datatable, I extract the data with this code. this.personas = res['results']; . if I try get like this res.results, a error occurs.